# GWT CellTable getRowElement throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception, gwt, celltable

I am using a CellTable in GWT and trying to add styling to a row whenever certain events happen.  The code to add styling is as follows:

```
Range range = playlistTable.getVisibleRange();
int start = range.getStart();

for (int i = start; i < start + playlistTable.getPageSize(); i++) {

     if (playlistData.get(i) == currentSong) {
            playlistTable.getRowElement(i).addClassName("highlightRow");

     } else {
            playlistTable.getRowElement(i).removeClassName("highlightRow");
     }
 }
```

When the app loads and the first page of the cell table is displayed, everything works perfectly.  However when I scroll to the next page and make a call to the above code, GWT throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException.  It does not like my index when I make the call to getRowElement, which only occurs if the index is "not on the current page."  It's as though getRowElement always thinks the current page is the first page.  If I scroll back to the first page, everything behaves fine.  Has anybody encountered this?  Am i missing something or is this a bug in GWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that `start` is `0` on the page that works. What happens if you do `playlistTable.getRowElement(i - start)` ? You may have to throw a `+ 1` or a `- 1` in somewhere.

Comment: Doh.  You are right -- each page starts at index 0.  playlistTable.getRowElement(i-start) did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but your code would be much simpler with [`RowStyles`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/RowStyles.html)

```
// do it only once!
playlistTable.setRowStyles(new RowStyles<Song>() {
  @Override
  public String getStyleNames(Song row, int rowIndex) {
    return (row == currentSong) ? "highlightRow": "";
  }
});
```

You might also want to use `equals()` and/or some `ProvidesKey` object to compare the `row` with the `currentSong`.

Comment: Wow thanks, that worked perfectly.  That was much easier than what i had been doing.